# Query on Dynamodb with GSI along with extra Attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, aws-sdk-js

I am new to dynamodb. I am trying to query on GSI `PlatformIndex`, Where `platform = "x"` and it'll be sorted by `tx_time`. But I also need to match another attribute `senderWallet = "y"`. I think this can be done by adding `FilterExpression` after making the query. I believe it is a costly read approach. Is there any better/optimized approach to obtain the result?

To put it more simple form, Is it possible to perform such query where 2 attribute(`platform` and `senderWallet`) will match with given data and it will be sorted by `tx_time` in asc/dsc order?

- `tx_time` is timestamp.
- `senderWallet` and `platform` is string data type.

Thank you. Please let me know if there is any trouble understanding the problem.

**Schema:**

```js
AttributeDefinitions: [{
      AttributeName: 'txHash',
      AttributeType: 'S',
    },
    {
      AttributeName: 'senderWallet',
      AttributeType: 'S',
    },
    {
      AttributeName: 'tx_time',
      AttributeType: 'N',
    },
    {
      AttributeName: 'platform',
      AttributeType: 'S',
    }]
    
GlobalSecondaryIndexes: [{
      IndexName: 'PlatformIndex',
      KeySchema: [
        {
          AttributeName: 'platform',
          KeyType: 'HASH',
        },
        {
          AttributeName: 'tx_time',
          KeyType: 'RANGE',
        },
      ],
      Projection: {
        ProjectionType: 'ALL',
      },
    }]
```

**QueryCode**

```js
    const query = {
      TableName: userTxHistorySchema.TableName,
      IndexName: 'PlatformIndex',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':platform': platform,
        ':senderWallet': senderWallet,
      },
      ScanIndexForward: false,
      KeyConditionExpression: 'platform = :platform',
      Limit: limit,
      ExclusiveStartKey: lastEvaluatedKey,
      FilterExpression: 'senderWallet = :senderWallet', // Need to optimise this condition while executing the read query
    };

    const response = await queryItems(query);
    console.log('response', response);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few choices.

The easiest design is you create a GSI where the PK is the two values concatenated together (platform#sender) and the SK is your timestamp. No need to filter.

This value concatenation approach is extremely common with DynamoDB.

Comment: I think this will solve my problem. Thanks a lot man!